# I want to know which method is called by this /api/2.0.alpha1/issue/{issueKey} in JIRA

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

> Please can you let me know which method is called by
>   /api/2.0.alpha1/issue/{issueKey} in JIRA  reference :
>   http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/4.4.3/#id2413591
>
> I need this to see how these methods are implemented and how it
>   retrieves all the issues in JSON format ? I want to get all issues in
>   JIRA at once. Is there a method to get all issues in JIRA for a
>   particular filter (Requset ID) without knowing the issue id .

My need is that I want them in JSON format , hence I am trying this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jira development (or any other atlassian products) i recommend you to download the [atlassian-plugin-sdk](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Introduction+to+the+Atlassian+Plugin+SDK). Just uncompress the sdk somewhere and run the following commend:

```
./atlas-run-standalone --product jira --version 5.0.7
```

To run a jira instance with the current 5.0.7 version. That will invoke some maven magic and your server should be running soon ;) To use the *4.4.3* version, just alter the version string.

Once you have your jira server started, open your [browser](http://yourhost.lan:2990/jira).
The default username and password is *admin*.

Open the Administation panel -> [REST API browser](http://yourhost.lan:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/restbrowser). There you can choose all the available REST interfaces, i guess you will need the *Alassian JIRA - Plugins - REST Plugin http://yourhost.lan:2990/jira/rest/api/2*. (If you use a jira version >= 5.0)

I recommend you to read the [REST API Tutorials](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Tutorials), for testing [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) comes very handy.

To get all the issues just execute something like the following:

```
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/search
```

*hth*

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to get all issues in JIRA for a particular filter (Requset ID) without knowing the issue id

Yes. You can do this by using JQL search

```
/api/2.0.alpha1/search?jql&startAt&maxResults
```